# ¿Como evitar que una variable de session caduque por inactividad?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar de antemano gracias.

Tengo una variable de sesion que la obtengo de un webform.aspx de un usuario para después pasarla a otro webform que pertenece a otro usuario.

Mi problema es que esta session caduca si el otro usuario no revisa su formulario de manera inmediata provocando que no pueda hacer sus operaciones ya que la variable de session caduca.

Mi pregunta es:
**¿Como puedo hacer para que esta variable de session no caduque por varias horas o dias?**

Este es mi código:

```
//** Formulario de Usuario Juan
[WebMethod]
    public static string Obtener_Regiones(string Region) 
    {
        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();          

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable tabla_Intervalo = new DataTable();
        DataTable tabla_imagenIntervalo = new DataTable();           
        ds = t.Mostrar_Intervalo(Region);

        //*** Creacion de variable de session ***//
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Region"] = Region;

        tabla_Intervalo = ds.Tables[0];            

        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Intervalo,Formatting.Indented);

        return datos;             

    }
    /****************************************************************************************************/

    //** Formulario de usuario Carlos
    protected void btnDescargar_Reporte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();    
        DataTable reporte = new DataTable();

        // Recupero la variable de session
        string region = Session["Region"].ToString();

        reporte = t.Reportes_Region(Region);

     // Crecion de reporte con crystal reports
        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/Reporte_Region.rpt"));
        rpt.SetDataSource(reporte);


        rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,Response,true,"Reporte");


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las variables de sesión caducan siempre. El tiempo de caducidad depende de la configuración del sitio web establecido en el web.config.

Dentro del web.config tienes diferentes apartados. Dentro de 
     `<system.web>` 
puedes poner por ejemplo
     `<sessionState timeout="720" />`

esto indica que la caducidad de la sesión será de 720 minutos (12 horas).